# How does batch size impact time execution in neural networks?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, convolution

I am using CNN (convolution neural network) model to train cifar10.
I tried to change the batch size at each execution to see its impact on time

My conclusion was : the bigger the batch size the more time the model took to be executed.

Does this seem logical because at the end of every batch we apply back propagation algorithm, meaning with larger batch size we apply less gradient descent so logically we should have less execution time.

I found the opposite. What do you think guys ! 
Thanks

Here is my session code :

```
       with tf.Session() as sess:
         sess.run(init)
         summary_writer =tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path,graph=tf.get_default_graph())
        start_time = time.time()
        for i in range(iteration_number):
          j = (i - epoch) * batch_size % number_of_examples
          k= (i - epoch + 1) * batch_size % number_of_examples
          if (k < j): # THE END OF DATA SET ------------------------
            k = number_of_examples
            batch_x = train_images[j:number_of_examples, :]
            batch_y = train_labels[j:number_of_examples, :]
            print("Iter " + str(i) + ", epoch Loss= " + \
                    "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                    "{:.5f}".format(acc))

            data = numpy.concatenate((train_images, train_labels), axis=1)
            numpy.random.shuffle(data)
            train_images = data[:, :3072]
            train_labels = data[:, 3072:3082]
            epoch = i + 1

          else:
            batch_x = train_images[j:k, :]
            batch_y = train_labels[j:k, :]
            loss, acc, summary = sess.run([cost, accuracy, merged_summary_op], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                        y: batch_y,
                                                        keep_prob: 0.3})
            summary_writer.add_summary(summary)

            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y,
                                        keep_prob: dropout})
```

Comment: Ignoring complicated convergence-stuff (with different convergence-behaviour time_per_epoch is not a valid metric to reason about how long it takes to train my model): bigger batches = more parallelization and therefore less time per epoch (if there is enough memory).

Comment: Show us the code. My first guess is that you are calling a function that run a fixed number of batches is an epoch, not a fixed number of samples.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski thanks for your comment, i did not understand very well what you mean but here I added my code

Comment: @sascha Thank you very much ! what do you mean by more parallelization ?

Comment: CPU or GPU can do more calculations per time given their hardware. This basically means that in practice you won't see batch_size=1 although it has probably the best convergence-theory. But as convergence-behaviour differs depending on batch-size and there are no simple rules, tuning batch-size is something which one should do.

Comment: @sascha ok but what does this has to do with the batch size ... GPU will do more calculation with either batch size = 64 or batch size = 256 isn't it ?

Comment: Do some basic research first. There are tons of courses. (yeah, the difference between 64 and 256 in regards to parallelization might not be much; but it might be between 8 and 32).

Comment: Is number_of_examples a fixed number?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski yes it is, it is equal to 50 000 the number of training images

Comment: (i - epoch) * batch_size % number_of_examples - what do you want to achieve here? The left side of modulo is smaller than the right, so in turn you always get (i - epoch) * batch_size. Also, it would seem from the code (sorry, but it's rather messy) that increasing the batch size does not lower the number of iterations. You just take more images per epoch and in turn the process takes longer.

Answer (score 1):

The batch size basically indicates how often you want to adjust the weights for your neural network. A batch size of 1 would mean you give your NN 1 input and output pair, propagate the network with the inputs, calculate the error and adjust the weights.
If you have a batch size the same as your datasets size, the NN will propagate all the input output pairs and add up the error and adjust the weights in the end. using a batch size that big usually gives you less accurate results but they are better suiting the average, you could say the outputs get kind of blurred out to avoid extremely big errors for some data and extremely small error for other data.